# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una matriz de números binarios generada aleatoriamente a decimales en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy realizando un pequeño programa en python que me permita realizar la conversión de binario a decimal, les planteo:

El código pide al usuario el numero de binarios a generar y la cantidad que deben contener el numero binario, aleatoriamente se realiza esta combinación. una vez que tengo la matriz con los números en binario, debo convertir a decimal cada numero generado. Al momento de realizar la conversión me produce el siguiente error:

*Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 32, in ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: ' '*

mi código es el siguiente:

```
import json 
import random

binarios = input('Escriba el número de binarios a generar:')
binarios=int(binarios)
digitos = input('Escriba la cantidad de digitos a utilizar:')
digitos=int(digitos)

matriz = [[0 for x in range(digitos)] for x in range(binarios)]

for i in range(binarios):
   for j in range(digitos):
      matriz[i][j] = random.randint(0, 1) 
    
print (matriz)

lista = matriz
cadena = json.dumps(lista)
newstring = cadena.replace("[","")
new1 = newstring.replace("]]","]")
new2 = new1.replace("]","\n")
new3 = new2.replace(",","")
new4 = new3.replace(" ","")
new5 = new4.replace("\n"," ")

numerofinal = int(new5, 2)
print(numerofinal)
```

En espera de una orientación, quedo pendiente, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tengas errores de este tipo, lo primero es agregar un `print` para ver con que estás trabajando:

```
new5 = new4.replace("\n", " ")

print(type(new5), new5) => <class 'str'> 101 011 001 000
```

Como ves, `new5` contiene una secuencia de binarios separados por espacios; todo lo que se necesita es separarlos y procesarlos uno a uno:

```
for binario in new5.split():
    numerofinal = int(binario, 2)
    print(numerofinal)
```

La función `split()` sin argumentos divide la cadena por los espacios en blanco.

Pero hay mejores y más simples formas para lograr el resultado. Lo primero es almacer los ceros y unos como cadenas, no como enteros. Eso me evita la necesidad de conversiones posteriores.

```
for i in range(binarios):
    for j in range(digitos):
        matriz[i][j] = "01"[random.randint(0, 1)]
```

Como `randint` me retorna 0 o 1, uso ese valor como índice para extraer un caracter de la cadena "01". Asi convierto de binario a cadena.

Ahora me resta recorrer la matriz línea por línea. Cada línea es una lista de caracteres. Los junto usando `join` y tengo el número binario. Lo convierto a entero y lo imprimo.

```
for binlist in matriz:
    binstr = ''.join(binlist)
    numerofinal = int(binstr, 2)
    print(binstr, numerofinal)
```

#### Demo

```
import random

binarios = input('Escriba el número de binarios a generar:')
binarios = int(binarios)
digitos = input('Escriba la cantidad de digitos a utilizar:')
digitos = int(digitos)

matriz = [[0 for _ in range(digitos)] for _ in range(binarios)]

for i in range(binarios):
    for j in range(digitos):
        matriz[i][j] = "01"[random.randint(0, 1)]

for binlist in matriz:
    binstr = ''.join(binlist)
    numerofinal = int(binstr, 2)
    print(binstr, numerofinal)
```

produce:

```
Escriba el número de binarios a generar:4
Escriba la cantidad de digitos a utilizar:3
010 2
101 5
100 4
100 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```